# Acces, open, or edit a webview from FCM notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-webview, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented android FCM in my application , my App only loads a web application in the WebView.

I wanna change the url of webview after receiving (and click) of FCM notification.
I manage the notification in "MyFirebaseMessagingService.java", specifically in sendNotification method.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Principal.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

/*HERE I WANNA ACCES, CREATE OR EDIT A WEBVIEW*/


    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Formación Alcalá")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(messageBody))
            .setContentText(messageBody);



    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**I think this should be possible. Please , someone could guide me** ?
P.D. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you can pass URL in parameter of intent and load that URL in webview .

Comment: @Himani thanks for your answer, ¿can you paste a example? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra("URl", Your URL);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent =      PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),notificationIndex,notification    Intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), notificationTitle,      notificationMessage, pendingNotificationIntent);
```

and in your main Activity :

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null){
    if(extras.containsKey("NotificationMessage"))
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.viewmain);
        // extract the extra-data in the Notification
        String url= extras.getString("URl");
        webview.loadurl(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: In that particular part I should do webview.loadurl (url )    
it could be in the OnCreate method?.

Comment: but on oncreate method i don´t have a intent item

Comment: copy this Intent intent = getIntent();

Comment: I am using firebase, not android.notifications, it is affects? where you create a notification objetc? i not see in the code.

Comment: if you are use FCM it doesn't   affect at all . i create notification object in the first part of the code